# kivy says I have multiple screens with the same name

Tags: python, kivy

Kivy keeps telling me that I have multiple screens with the same name for all my screens and I don't have and i think that's why some code I am trying to run doesn't seem to work. need assistance.

here's my Window manager

```
<ScreenManager>:
    id: window manager
    Homepage:
        id: home
        name: "home"
    SignUpWindow:
        id: create
        name: "create"
    SignUp:
        id: signup
        name: "signup"
    LoginWindow:
        id: login
        name: "login"
    ProjectListScreen:
        id: project_list_screen
        name: "project_list_screen"
    ApplyPage:
        id: applyingpage
        name: "applyingpage"
    MainWindow:
        id: main
        name: "main"
    NewProjectScreen:
        id: placements
        name: "placements"
    ProfileWindow:
        id: page
        name: "page"
```

Comment: There must be something else going on. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, please provide the full code as the problem may be somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Kivy automatch the classes that inherit the App class with it's class's name. For example if your class that inherit the App class is `class TestApp(App) :`  it will be matched with test.kv or Test.kv

if you also used builder to load kv file (for example `with open("test.kv") as kvfile:`)  as a result, you would load kvfile twice. so you're system tell you that you have multiple screen name.

solution 1. change your kv file name.

Comment: Solution 2 ? ;)